# Add a description to "manufacturer" attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute

I want to display a description of the manucfacturer of a product, so that the customer can read more about the product's brand while viewing the product itself.

The most logical place to put this description is along with the actual Manucfacturer name as we have multiple products belonging to multiple brands. In my case the Manucfacturer are held within the "Attributes" section of the Magento backend. However, I have no facility there to add a description. I also don't know how to add a "description" field to this specific product attribute.

How can I add a field to the "Manucfacturer" attribute in Magento?

Comment: I'm sorry you can't. This is not how attributes work in magento.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom table and custom module to save your extra data for any attribute and map the data with option id. Or you can update and save these values using observwr